# How to programmatically upload local file as Django model field?

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I'm having troubles trying to upload files to `FileField` from local path.

I have correctly configurred CDN backend in `S3` bucket and use it as `PrivateMediaStorage` for one of my model fields:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    ...
```

With this very simple configuration whenever I'm creating/updating model through `django-admin` it is saved and file attached as `some_file` is correctly uploaded to `S3` bucket.

Yet if I try to create/update model instance programmatically, say through custom `manage.py` command, model instance itself is created but attachment is never uploaded to CDN. Here's simplified version of code I'm using to upload files:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates dummy instance for quicker configuration'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        some_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../../temporary/some_image.png')

        if not os.path.exists(some_file):
            raise CommandError(f'File {some_file} does not exist')
        else: 
            instance, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(defaults={'some_file': some_file}, ...)
```

What is missing in my implementation and what needs to be adjusted to allow file uploads from local storage?

Comment: You have to pass a `File` object to your model, not a string (your path is just a string).

Comment: See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) for how to save the file to your model

Comment: So I was missing `open(...)` and `File()` parts. Thanks @dirkgroten !

Comment: yeah but `get_or_create()` is not a good idea with just the file as argument. You can't really fetch the model for a file, use some other field to uniquely identify your files. Your current get_or_create will always create a new instance AFAIK.

Comment: @dirkgroten a very good point, but as you probably figured out this was just an example code for question, in reality body of `get_or_create` is much more extended and it is figurring out whether record already exists by other non-File fields.

Comment: Then you should move the file to the `defaults` parameter of `get_or_create` so that it’s not used for matching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing a string (the result of `os.path.join()`) to your `some_file` field, but you need to pass it an actual [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#the-file-object) object.

The easiest way to save a file on a model directly is to use the [`FieldFile`'s `save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) method.

As a working solution for case provided in question a valid way of creating a record would be:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(some_file=File(file=open(some_file, 'rb'), name='some_name.png'))
```

Or even better to use `pathlib` to obtain name dynamically:

```
from pathlib import Path

instance = MyModel.objects.create(some_file=File(file=open(some_file, 'rb'), name=Path(some_file).name))
```

Note that fetching a row based on the file is unlikely to work, AFAIK each time you open a file, doing a `get_or_create()` with the `File` instance as argument will probably create a new row each time. Better put file fields into `defaults`:

```
with open(some_file, 'rb') as file:
    instance, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(
        some_other_field=..., 
        defaults={'some_file': File(
            file=file, 
            name=pathlib.Path(some_file).name
            )}
    )
```

Comment: Don't we need to close the file after open. If yes, How can we do this properly.

Comment: Good point! Amended

Answer (score 1):

**you can also do something like this.**

```
      some_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../../temporary/some_image.png')
instance.some_file.name = some_file
instance.save()
```